# How to solve stripe error No such plan: 'monthly' laravel cashier

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using stripe "~5.0" and cashier "~7.0" and i have created 2 products on stripe dash board
[image]

but when i call new subscription package then i face error `No such plan: 'monthly'`
Controller code is

```
$user->newSubscription('default','monthly')->create($request->cc_token, [ 'email' => $user->email ]);
```

I have search but i can not find solutions. Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct identifier for the plan?

Comment: I  have only created product and use product name as lowercase i thnik this is as a plan id if i am wrong then please guide me

Comment: Now i am using Monthly and face error  `No such plan: 'Monthly'; one exists with a name of Monthly, but its ID is price_1HD3hgEft5GkDC4vjK2dq3AM.
`

Comment: So try using the identifier, as noted in the docs "The second argument is the specific plan the user is subscribing to. This value should correspond to the plan's price identifier in Stripe."

Comment: I can not understand identifier kindly give me example

Comment: i remember having a similar problem, go to the stripe interface to see the identifier for your plan, i very vaguely remember the identifier not being as expected. Check it in the interface, dont rely on your remembrance of the naming.

Comment: as the error implies, you should do `newSubscription('default','price_1HD3hgEft5GkDC4vjK2dq3AM')` instead. The `name` of the plan is not the same as its API ID.

Comment: It's my mistake because i can not send paymentintent from view so i solved this problem thanks alot